# Find numbers that differ by 1 digit from a set of 15,000 12-digit numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of ~15,000 12-digit barcoded tickets. Most of the time they are scanned off paper or phone screens, but sometimes they are typed in (cracked screens, etc.) How would I go about finding if we have any sets of codes that differ by 1 digit, so typing the first one with a mis-typed digit *might* end up with another valid code?

The code numbers are 12-digit integers that are fairly random in the range 100000000000 to 999999999999 (we don't want leading zeroes to give problems with other systems)

e.g. given  the three code numbers
123456789012
123456789013
223456789012

The first and second differ by only one digit and the second and third also. the first and third differ by 2 digits, so is ignored.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: A bit rude, no? This is a genuine request - we do barcoded entry for events and we occasionally get people who seem honest and swear they haven't let anybody else have their barcodes. We've changed the scanning software to log when codes are typed in instead of scanned, so I thought it would be interesting to do an analysis on the barcodes in use to see if there's a chance that they were mis-typed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash set. Go through each of your 15,000 numbers in turn, and for each one, generate the 108 different numbers that differ from it in one place (12 digits times 9 possible alternate digits in each place). Check if each of those 108 numbers exists in the hash set (without inserting them). If any one of them does then you have a hit. If not then add the unmodified number to the hash set and move onto the next one.

You could also try with transpositions of adjacent numbers, which would give you another 11 digits on top of the 108 to try.

Comment: What would be the advantage of generating a hash set as opposed to comparing the numbers?

Comment: You can check whether a number is in the hash set in O(1) instead of in O(n) to iterate over the numbers and check each one. Although, for only 15,000 numbers it's probably not going to be that slow to just do it the brute force way.